# How do I set a modifier in a coffeescript heregex?

Tags: regex, coffeescript

I have this heregex in coffeescript trying to catch urls:

```
regex = /// (
  ((f|ht){1}tp(s)?://)
  [-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~?&//=]+
  )
///
```

but how do set a global and ignore case flag?  I've tried this:

```
    newregex = regex.compile(regex,"gi")
```

but that doesn't work either

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Coffeescript converts your heregex into a single line regex:

```
//Generated by CoffeeScript 1.3.1
var regex;

regex = /(((f|ht){1}tp(s)?:\/\/)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~?&\/\/=]+)/;
```

And javascripts regex syntax `/regex/mods` is shorthand for regex.compile("regex","mods"), so you don't need to compile it.  You can just add the modifiers to the heregex:

```
regex = /// (
  ((f|ht){1}tp(s)?://)
  [-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~?&//=]+
  )
///gi
```

Comment: that worked for me.  I put it there the first time i was going to try it but Rubymine acted like it was the worst thing I ever did so I thought I'd get a compile error or something, but I ignored it and that worked.  I can find no documentation of modifiers on heregexes anywhere so it's good this is out there now.